# next js Router.push reloads page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I do `Router.push` my page reloads, I would expect pushState to be used.

Using the following code in the component:

```
import Router from "next/router";
//other code
const search = useCallback(
  e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Router.push(
      `/products-search/${encodeURIComponent(
        searchText
      )}`,
      `/products-search?q=${encodeURIComponent(
        searchText
      )}`
    );
  },
  [searchText]
);
//other code
<form onSubmit={search}>
  <input
    type="text"
    onChange={change}
    value={searchText}
    pattern=".{3,}"
    title="3 characters minimum"
    required
  />
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

My page/products-search.js

```
ProductsSearch.getInitialProps = ({ query, store }) => {
  //added try catch as next js may reload if there is an error
  //  running this on the client side
  try {
    const queryWithPage = withPage(query);
    return {
      query: queryWithPage
    };
  } catch (e) {
    debugger;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I pass an object to `Router.push` it works as expected:

```
const search = useCallback(
  e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Router.push({
      pathname: "/products-search",
      query: { q: searchText }
    });
  },
  [searchText]
);
```

Answer (score 14):

In case some lost soul comes here with my issue, it was kind of invisible.

```
router.push(
      '/organizations/[oid]/clients/[uid]',
      `/organizations/${oid}/clients/${id}`
    );
```

is what I wrote and it navigated without a refresh.

```
router.push(
      '/organizations/[oid]/clients/[cid]',// cid mistaken name but still worked. Should be uid
      `/organizations/${oid}/clients/${id}`
    );
```

The mistaken id name was causing the refresh, though it still navigated to the right page.
So, make sure the id names are correct.

Answer (score -1):

const search = () => {
  router.push(
   `/products-search/[searchText]`, 
   `/products- search/${searchText}`,
    {shallow: true}
 );

}